# Error while trying to program a discord bot using pycharm

Tags: python, discord, pycharm, bots

I had a problem with making a discord bot with python im using pycharm
I this happens when I try to run my script

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/czeni/PycharmProjects/Molta Bot/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "C:\Users\czeni\PycharmProjects\Molta Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\czeni\PycharmProjects\Molta Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\czeni\PycharmProjects\Molta Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\czeni\PycharmProjects\Molta Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

It appears as though you have not passed a value to the 'TOKEN' environment variable. When loading an environment variable `os.getenv` will return `None` if the key passed (in this case 'TOKEN') does not exist.

### Fix

1. Create a file called '.env' in the same directory as your `main.py` file.
2. Add `TOKEN='your_token'` to the file.
3. In your environment, run `pip install python-dotenv`
4. Add the following code to your `main.py` file:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

### Reference

[`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv)

[`python-dotenv` and `load_dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#getting-started)